# Copy from one sheet to another and copy to the next row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Bill of Material.xlsx. I use to track the fabricated parts, purchased parts and electrical parts to make my life better. The BOM has many different sheets, but I will talk about two of them.

The first sheet is Called "Fabricated" where the drawing number and material, quantity and so forth. In that sheet column A8:A500 has a drop down list. In that list Vishay Redline, is my key trigger word.

The second sheet is called "Redline Fabricated". This sheet is were I will paste collect data from "Fabricated" so I can print it to give to the design engineers for changes. The array formula is looking for; "Vishay Redline" as the key lookup work, and then copy Cell 2,3,4, and so on, to the Redline Fabricated sheet. I did make a small change to that Arrayformula from my last post.

Here is my problem: if the Arrayformula find the (trigger work) on, let's say row 27, it will copy that data to the other sheet on row 27. And if the key word is found again on row 29, it will also copy it to row 29. So row 28 is blank.  I want to collect data from one page no matter where it's at and paste it one row after the other.  So when I print that page, everything will look neat.

The Array formula resides on the Redline Fabricated sheet A8:A500

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Vishay Redline",Fabricated!A8:W8,{2,3,4,5,8,9,23},0),""))
```

Comment: I would add the google-spreadsheet tag

Comment: Your explanation is confusing.  Are you trying to place the `Arrayformula` data into Redline Fabricated A23?  What are you trying to print?  What is 'Fabricated Cell A23' and what does it have to do with this?

Comment: I edited my post for a better description, Sorry if my first post was confusing, this is all new to me.  Learning as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for editing the post, and including the sample sheet.  It's much more clear now.

Trying to skip blanks with `vlookup` is not simple (for me at least).  I would do it with a `query` and `importrange`.

Try: `=query({importrange("__YOUR SS KEY ID HERE__","Fabricated!A8:W")},"select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col8, Col9, Col23 where Col1 contains 'Vishay Redline'",0)`.

This should only bring in rows that have 'Vishay Redline' in Column A.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It works great.  after a few trial runs some data did not copy over that had special characters and I finally figured out I had to format the cells to plain text.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  If you feel your question was answered, please accept the answer so others know it has been answered.  Good luck!